# Scala 2.8: _ behaviour changed?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

Using [XScalaWT](http://bitbucket.org/djo/xscalawt), this compiled under Scala 2.7:

```
class NodeView(parent: Composite) extends Composite(parent) {
  var nodeName: Label = null

  this.contains(
    label(
      nodeName = _
    )
  )
}
```

With 2.8.0 RC1, I get this error:

> type mismatch;  found   : main.scala.NodeView  required: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label

The types are:

```
label(setups: (Label => Unit)*)(parent: Composite) : Label
contains(setups: (W => Unit)*) : W
```

So it looks like _ now binds to the outer function instead of inner.

Is this change intentional?

**UPDATE**: Here is a minimized example:

Scala 2.7.7:

```
scala> var i = 0
i: Int = 0

scala> def conv(f: Int => Unit) = if (_:Boolean) f(1) else f(0)    
conv: ((Int) => Unit)(Boolean) => Unit

scala> def foo(g: Boolean => Unit) { g(true) }    
foo: ((Boolean) => Unit)Unit

scala> foo(conv(i = _))    

scala> i    
res4: Int = 1
```

Scala 2.8.0RC3:

```
scala> var i = 0
i: Int = 0

scala> def conv(f: Int => Unit) = if (_:Boolean) f(1) else f(0)
conv: (f: (Int) => Unit)(Boolean) => Unit

scala> def foo(g: Boolean => Unit) { g(true) }
foo: (g: (Boolean) => Unit)Unit

scala> foo(conv(i = _))
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean
 required: Int
       foo(conv(i = _))
                  ^

scala> foo(conv(j => i = j))

scala> i
res3: Int = 1
```

Interestingly enough, this works:

```
scala> foo(conv(println _))
1
```

Comment: Can you post more or the error message?

Comment: I did post the error message: "type mismatch; found : main.scala.NodeView required: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label"

Comment: Which line does the compiler refer to?

Comment: It should be working again in RC6.

Comment: Yes, I know and am happy about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer I got from Lukas Rytz on the scala-user list:

> Hi Alexey,
>
> there has been a change in semantics
>   when we introduced named arguments. An
>   expression
>
> ```
> foo(a = _)
> ```
>
> used to be parsed as follows:
>
> ```
> foo(x => a = x)
> ```
>
> In 2.8, "a" is treated as a named
>   argument, i.e. the expression is
>   parsed as:
>
> ```
> x => foo(a = x)
> ```
>
> I will add a migration warning for
>   this change.

Comment: In some cases, you might get the old behaviour with curly braces instead.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing and asked on Dave's blog:

http://www.coconut-palm-software.com/the_new_visual_editor/doku.php?id=blog:simplifying_swt_with_scala#comment__930ba2f0a020203873d33decce01ebc2

No answer there yet though. Just as you're saying, it seems like the _ binds to the outer closure rather than the inner one.

Changing

```
nodeName = _
```

to

```
x => nodeName = x
```

fixes the problem.

Comment: Yes, but it hurts the readability of XScalaWT code for me quite a bit.

Comment: Yes, sure, and it's really weird that the semantics of _ changed that drastically. I would really like to understand what has happened too.

Comment: If you didn't see the answer yet, it isn't the semantics of _ which changed, but of =.